# WPF Combobox DataBound to a DataTable, Refresh automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have one `combobox` that I am `databinding` to a `DataTable` which is fetching the data from database as follows:

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter
    (@"SELECT [CategoryID],[CategoryName]FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Categories]", 
     @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=AKSHAY-PC\SQLEXPRESS");

DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(tbl);

cmbCities.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)tbl).GetList();

cmbCities.DisplayMemberPath = "[CategoryName]";
cmbCities.SelectedValuePath = "[CategoryID]";
```

When the table data is changed(added/removed rows), the `combobox` does not get refreshed because `IList` does not have the change notification built it.

Is there any way it can be made possible?

If it's not possible, is there any way to "refresh" the databinding so that the `datatable` will fetch the data again. In this case, what I will do is execute the above code when the window is initialized and then refresh it again without needing to execute the same code again. Something like `cmbCities.Data.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will clear and fill the combobox from your sql adapter when you click the corresponding buttons.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox Name="cmbCities" />
        <Button Content="Clear" Click="OnClear"/>
        <Button Content="Fill" Click="OnFill"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _adp.Fill(_tbl);

            cmbCities.ItemsSource = ((IListSource)_tbl).GetList();

            cmbCities.DisplayMemberPath = "[CategoryName]";
            cmbCities.SelectedValuePath = "[CategoryID]";

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void OnClear(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _tbl.Clear();
        }

        private void OnFill(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _adp.Fill(_tbl);
        }

        private DataTable _tbl = new DataTable();
        private SqlDataAdapter _adp = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT [CategoryID],[CategoryName]FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Categories]", @"Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=AKSHAY-PC\SQLEXPRESS");

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wallstreet, but still I have to click the buttons to see the update.

Comment: I added the buttons to allow you to easily see that your DB was requried. It is sample code that I hoped you would be able to learn from and adapt to your specific needs. 
So here's how to use it in your case given your question: You should in your code call _tbl.Clear() followed by _adp.Fill(_tbl) in some function that gets called when you need to refresh your data binding because the underlying data have changed.